# How to set different Launch Images for different targets on Xcode on iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to set different Launch Images for different targets on Xcode on iOS application?

When I'm trying to do it for the second target Xcode renames it to Default.png and shows warning that file is already exists.

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set differant base name for launch screen file name by assigning it as value of **UILaunchImageFile** in your Info.plist file.

Read more about it from Apple documentation on [App Related Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html).

Specifically for 4 inch iOS devices (iPhone 5 and iPod)

> To specify default launch images for iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th
>   generation) devices, include the modifier string -568h immediately
>   after the  portion of the filename. Because these devices
>   have Retina displays, the @2x modifier must always be included with
>   launch images for the devices. For example, the default launch image
>   name for a device is Default-568h@2x.png. (If your app has the
>   UILaunchImageFile key in its Info.plist file, replace the Default
>   portion of the string with your custom string.) The -568h modifier
>   should always be the first one in the list.